# Tk::GraphViz Zooming

Tags: perl, graphviz, tk-toolkit

I've been trying to plot a connectivity graph using `Tk::GraphViz`.

I have the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk::GraphViz;
use Tk;


my $graph ='graph PathsOfPin {
    a [label = "aaa"];
    b [label = "bbb"];
    c [label = "ccc"];
    d [label = "ddd"];
    e [label = "eee"];
    f [label = "fff"];
    a--b;
    c--d;
    e--f;
    b--c;
    d--e;
}';
my $mw = new MainWindow();
my $gv = $mw->GraphViz ( qw/-width 800 -height 800/ )->pack ( qw/-expand yes -fill both/ );

$gv->fit(); # This does nothing - down't affect the view
$gv->zoom( -in => 100 ); # This gives me error
$gv->show ( $graph );
MainLoop;
```

When I try to run the code without `fit` and `zoom` , I get this really tiny graph (looks like a dot), which I need to zoom in with the mouse several times until I see it as I should.

1. I tried the `fit`, which supposed to fit the graph to view - but it doesn't really work.
2. When I try hard-coding the zoom with the `$gv-zoom`, I get the following error:

   ```
   Tk::Error: Can't set -scrollregion to ARRAY(0xbb8d30) for Tk::GraphViz=HASH(0xd1bbb0): bad       scrollRegion "???" at /5.8.5/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux/Tk/Configure.pm line 46.
   at /5.8.5/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux/Tk/Derived.pm line 294
   Tk callback for .
   Tk callback for .graphviz
   Tk callback for .graphviz
   Tk::Derived::configure at 5.8.5/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux/Tk/Derived.pm line 306
   Tk::GraphViz::_scaleAndMoveView at GraphViz.pm line 1445
   Tk::GraphViz::zoom at Tk/GraphViz.pm line 1864
   Can't set -scrollregion to ARRAY(0xbb8d30) for Tk::GraphViz=HASH(0xd1bbb0): bad scrollRegion "???" at 5.8.5/x86_64-linux/Tk/Configure.pm line 46.
   at 5.8.5/x86_64-linux/Tk/Derived.pm line 294
   ```

Is the a better way to auto fit the graph to the zoom?

Answer (score 0):

There is! Doing either a `zoom` or a `fit` *before* the `show` is going to cause big problems. If you omit the `zoom`, and do the `fit` after the show, everything works in the current code on `master` of the repo.

This code now works:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk::GraphViz;
use Tk;

my $graph ='graph PathsOfPin {
    a [label = "aaa"];
    b [label = "bbb"];
    c [label = "ccc"];
    d [label = "ddd"];
    e [label = "eee"];
    f [label = "fff"];
    a--b;
    c--d;
    e--f;
    b--c;
    d--e;
}';

my $mw = new MainWindow();
my $gv = $mw->Scrolled('GraphViz', qw/-scrollbars osoe -width 800 -height 800/ )->pack ( qw/-expand no -fill both/ );

$gv->show ( $graph );
$gv->fit();
$mw->update;
MainLoop;
```

By the time you read this, the updated version of the library will be on CPAN. Various fixes were necessary to handle changes in DOT's output format. It seems to work well now. Please give it a try, and report any problems in a GitHub issue.